# Python program to convert strings to division

Tags: python-3.x, string, python-2.7, coding-style, converters

I am trying to resolve this string conversion to division.
here is the problem, I have three input of strings s1('1/2'),  s2('2/3) and s3('+').
I should get result = 7/6

I was trying to
def string('1/2','2/3','+'):
  result = float(1/2) + float(2/3)

Can't think of much, any inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
from fractions import Fraction #this is required to use the "Fraction" command 
s1 = Fraction(1,2) #nominator first, denominator second
s2 = Fraction(2,3)
S = s1+s2
print(S)
```

You will see this on your monitor:
7/6